# Sorting a "find" result by field N from the *end* of each filen

Tags: bash, sorting, awk

I am trying to sort the result from a "find" command according to a particular field. I wish "sort" had a flag for sorting from the end (what's so special about left to right?)

I'm generating a list of files like in this example:

```
find . -name "S1A*1S*SAFE"

./A/B/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDH_20140512T054812_20140512T054842_000560_000716_3F8E.SAFE
./A/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDH_20140512T054812_20140512T054842_000560_000716_01AD.SAFE
./A/B/C/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20140525T060238_20140525T060309_000750_000B43_4EFA.SAFE
./A/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20140523T173226_20140523T173256_000728_000A3A_4073.SAFE
./A/B/C/D/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20140523T173226_20140523T173256_000728_000A3A_D26E.SAFE
```

I want to sort this list of files based on the first date field (e.g. 20140523T173226), but there is no way to know what the path to the file will be. I figure I need to somehow sort based on the 5th field from the end of the filename (maybe there's another way?) given a "_" delimiter.

So far the best I was able to come up with was this:

```
find . -name "S1A*1S*SAFE" | rev | awk -F '/' '{print $1}' | rev | sort -t _ -k 5
```

It reverses the file names, outputs everything until the first "/" symbol and then undoes the reverse operation, and then it can sort by the 5th field (with "_" as the delimiter).
It generates:

```
S1A_IW_SLC__1SDH_20140512T054812_20140512T054842_000560_000716_01AD.SAFE
S1A_IW_SLC__1SDH_20140512T054812_20140512T054842_000560_000716_3F8E.SAFE
S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20140523T173226_20140523T173256_000728_000A3A_4073.SAFE
S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20140523T173226_20140523T173256_000728_000A3A_D26E.SAFE
S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20140525T060238_20140525T060309_000750_000B43_4EFA.SAFE
```

This is nice - except I need to retain the entire path for each file, and awk strips it away in this example.

Is there any way to adjust this method - or use a completely different approach - that does what I need? I'm doing it in bash; I would prefer no perl etc. because I can't control what our IT group installs etc. (bash is reliable).

Comment: `$NF` in awk is the value of the last field, so you don't need to rev/rev to get it.

Comment: @EtanReisner both `awk` and `rev` processes could be saved.

Comment: @Kent He said he needs the full path. I meant to comment on your answer about that actually.

Comment: @EtanReisner oh, my bad. I thought he is looking for some better way to do the same thing as he's done.. you can post an answer.

Comment: It doesn't solve his problem either though because that would still lose the path. Though one could use that in part of an answer with some work.

Comment: @EtanReisner ok then I would post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find ... | awk -F_ '{print $(NF-4) "\t" $0}' | sort -k1 | cut -f2-
```

The above just copies the `_`-delimited 5th-from-the end string (the date you care about) to the front of the line followed by a tab character, then sorts using that and then strips out the field plus tab that awk had added.

Using `cat file` to replicate your `find` output just for this example (you would not normally cat a file to awk):

```
$ cat file
./A/B/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDH_20140512T054812_20140512T054842_000560_000716_3F8E.SAFE
./A/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDH_20140512T054812_20140512T054842_000560_000716_01AD.SAFE
./A/B/C/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20140525T060238_20140525T060309_000750_000B43_4EFA.SAFE
./A/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20140523T173226_20140523T173256_000728_000A3A_4073.SAFE
./A/B/C/D/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20140523T173226_20140523T173256_000728_000A3A_D26E.SAFE
$
$ cat file | awk -F_ '{print $(NF-4) "\t" $0}'
20140512T054812 ./A/B/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDH_20140512T054812_20140512T054842_000560_000716_3F8E.SAFE
20140512T054812 ./A/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDH_20140512T054812_20140512T054842_000560_000716_01AD.SAFE
20140525T060238 ./A/B/C/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20140525T060238_20140525T060309_000750_000B43_4EFA.SAFE
20140523T173226 ./A/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20140523T173226_20140523T173256_000728_000A3A_4073.SAFE
20140523T173226 ./A/B/C/D/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20140523T173226_20140523T173256_000728_000A3A_D26E.SAFE
$
$ cat file | awk -F_ '{print $(NF-4) "\t" $0}' | sort -k1
20140512T054812 ./A/B/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDH_20140512T054812_20140512T054842_000560_000716_3F8E.SAFE
20140512T054812 ./A/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDH_20140512T054812_20140512T054842_000560_000716_01AD.SAFE
20140523T173226 ./A/B/C/D/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20140523T173226_20140523T173256_000728_000A3A_D26E.SAFE
20140523T173226 ./A/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20140523T173226_20140523T173256_000728_000A3A_4073.SAFE
20140525T060238 ./A/B/C/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20140525T060238_20140525T060309_000750_000B43_4EFA.SAFE
$
$ cat file | awk -F_ '{print $(NF-4) "\t" $0}' | sort -k1 | cut -f2-
./A/B/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDH_20140512T054812_20140512T054842_000560_000716_3F8E.SAFE
./A/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDH_20140512T054812_20140512T054842_000560_000716_01AD.SAFE
./A/B/C/D/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20140523T173226_20140523T173256_000728_000A3A_D26E.SAFE
./A/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20140523T173226_20140523T173256_000728_000A3A_4073.SAFE
./A/B/C/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20140525T060238_20140525T060309_000750_000B43_4EFA.SAFE
```

Comment: For the record, here's what I did (based on your suggestion): find . -name "S1A*1S*SAFE" | awk -F/ '{print $NF"/"$0}' | sort -t_ -k 5,5 | cut -d/ -f 2-    Very clever! A couple of others had similar ideas but this is the one that "clicks" for me - as a newbie. I'm quite astounded at how many people chimed in...thanks everyone!

Comment: Ed, isn't the answer I selected yours? I'm not sure what you mean by yours being "simpler, briefer...". I do wonder though: is the last "-" in "-f2-" a typo? The final "-" seems to make no difference.

Comment: The answer you selected is mine but the comment you left says the solution you actually USED is different from mine (looks like it's the one provided by @EtanReisner), hence my question `Why?`. The `-` is deliberate. `-f2` says `select the second field` while `-f2-` says `select the second AND SUBSEQUENT fields`. You will see the difference if/when your file or directory names output by `find` contain tabs.

Comment: Ah - I see what you mean. What I actually used was: find . -name "S1A*1S*SAFE" | awk -F'_' '{print $(NF-4) "\t" $0}' | sort | cut -f2-

Comment: OK. FWIW this is a very common problem and adding tab-separated key field(s) before the original input line like this is always THE way to do this since it's what sort and cut expect (unless of course the keys themselves contain tabs). The only thing that varies is how to write the awk command to add the initial key field(s) for sorting.

Answer (score 1):

Dirty and quick solution would be:

- get the part you want to sort
- add it to the beginning of each line
- sort
- remove the added part from output

for testing, I save your `find` output into a file called `f`, you can do it with `find`

```
kent$  cat f
./A/B/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDH_20140512T054812_20140512T054842_000560_000716_3F8E.SAFE
./A/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDH_20140512T054812_20140512T054842_000560_000716_01AD.SAFE
./A/B/C/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20140525T060238_20140525T060309_000750_000B43_4EFA.SAFE
./A/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20140523T173226_20140523T173256_000728_000A3A_4073.SAFE
./A/B/C/D/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20140523T173226_20140523T173256_000728_000A3A_D26E.SAFE

kent$  awk -F_ '$0=$(NF-4)"\x99"$0' f |sort|sed 's/.*\x99//'
./A/B/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDH_20140512T054812_20140512T054842_000560_000716_3F8E.SAFE
./A/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDH_20140512T054812_20140512T054842_000560_000716_01AD.SAFE
./A/B/C/D/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20140523T173226_20140523T173256_000728_000A3A_D26E.SAFE
./A/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20140523T173226_20140523T173256_000728_000A3A_4073.SAFE
./A/B/C/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20140525T060238_20140525T060309_000750_000B43_4EFA.SAFE
```

Comment: This is good to know but it has the same problem I mentioned for my own solution: it loses the paths. I need the sorted list *including* the paths to the files (because otherwise I don't know where they are afterwards).

Comment: @phaseshift then I came up  with a dirty and quick solution: `find | sed (or awk) | sort |sed(or awk)`

Comment: @phaseshift see the updated answer for the solution.

Comment: I have to admit I don't know too much about sed, but doesn't the kind of solution you're proposing involve mangling (or losing) the path somehow? The sorting itself isn't too hard (as the suggestions already show) but the trick is keeping the output of "find" unmangled so we can do something with the files afterwards.

Comment: @phaseshift the sed line is just removing everything from beginning till the invisible char `\x99`. No, it won't lose path information. because I leave your find result part untouched. You can see that in the testing/example in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly pretty but it works. Uses <kbd>/</kbd> as output delimiter since we know that can't show up in the value of `$NF`.

```
find . -name "S1A*1S*SAFE" | awk -F/ '{print $NF"/"$0}' | sort -t_ -k 5,5 | cut -d/ -f 2-
```